# How to get rid of the two bars in bootstrap tab page

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, tabs

My bootstrap tabs looks like this:

[image: My bootstrap tabs]

As you can see, pointed by the two red arrows are two horizontal bars that I need to get rid of. They are not the borders. How do I get rid of them?

```css
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  color: black;
  /*rgb(240,90,42);*/
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 172);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  border: solid 1px rgb(204, 205, 90);
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  color: black;
  /*rgb(240,90,42);*/
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tab-pane {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.tab-content {
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(204, 205, 90);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(204, 205, 90);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(204, 205, 90);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#studentsTabPage">Students</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#studentDetailsTabPage">Student Details</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#exclusionsTabPage">Exclusions & Inclusions</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="exclusionsTabPage" class="tab-pane fade">

  </div>

  <div id="studentDetailsTabPage" class="tab-pane fade">

  </div>

  <div id="exclusionsTabPage" class="tab-pane fade">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an example in jsfiddle or codepen, I can't really get the 2 lines, even I copied your code.

Comment: I worked out how to get rid of the bottom line. There is a class defined somewhere: active {   border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCD44;  }. However I don't know how to get rid of the top line. jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Frank_from_Melbourne/jf0457sp/

Comment: I worked out: .nav-tabs {  border:none; }. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove bottom border for this class `.nav-tabs` and add border top for this class `.tab-content`

```
 .tab-content {
    border: 1px solid rgb(204,205,90);
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
  }

.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Check this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo1npqdx/700/)**

Answer (score 0):

Worked out why. Somewhere there is a css:

```
active { border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCD44; }
```

Once I remove it, the bottom bar is gone. Then, I add following css to get rid of the top bar:

```
.nav-tabs { border:none; }
```